# Add value in the array and then return true option

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a doubt in a script where I am doing a quiz. In my last quiz I put 3 answer choices: A, B and C. if the answer is "A", sum 3 points for "X" option, 2 points for "Y" option and 1 point to "Z" option. If the answer is "B" , sum  2 points for option "X", 3 points to  "Y" option and 1 point for "Z" option. If the answer is "C" , sum  1 points for option "X", 2 points to  "Y" option and 3 point for "Z" option.

The function checks the points of options A, B and C and returns the option which has the highest number of points.

But I want to change:

If answer is "A" accumulates 4 points. If answer is "B" accumulates 2 points. If answer is "C" accumulates 0 points.

If the point total is equal or less than 10 returns the "X" option. If the point total is greater than 10 and less than 24 returns "Y" option. If the point total is greater than 24 returns the  "Z" option.

Code:

```
self.jobs = [{
  title: 'Opção X',
  description: 'Descrição Opção X'
}, {
  title: 'Opção Y',
  description: 'Descrição Opção Y'
}, {
  title: 'Opção Z',
  description: 'Descrição Opção Z'
}];

self.job = 9999;

self.questions = [{
  text: 'Pergunta 1',
  answered: false,
  skipped: false,
  answers: [{
    text: 'A',
    selected: false,
    values: [3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    text: 'B',
    selected: false,
    values: [2, 3, 1]
  }, {
    text: 'C',
    selected: false,
    values: [1, 2, 3]
  }]
}, {
  text: 'Pergunta 2',
  answered: false,
  skipped: false,
  answers: [{
    text: 'A',
    selected: false,
    values: [3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    text: 'B',
    selected: false,
    values: [2, 3, 1]
  }, {
    text: 'C',
    selected: false,
    values: [1, 2, 3]
  }]
}, {
  text: 'Pergunta 3',
  answered: false,
  skipped: false,
  answers: [{
    text: 'A',
    selected: false,
    values: [3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    text: 'B',
    selected: false,
    values: [2, 3, 1]
  }, {
    text: 'C',
    selected: false,
    values: [1, 2, 3]
  }]
}];

self.index = 0;

self.userAnswers = [];

self.error = false;

self.answerQuestion = function(elem) {
  self.userAnswers[self.index] = elem.answer;
  self.index = elem.$parent.$index + 1;

  var question = elem.$parent.question;
  question.answered = true;

  angular.forEach(question.answers, function(answer) {
    answer.selected = false;
  });

  elem.answer.selected = true;
};

self.changeQuestion = function(elem) {
  var question = self.questions[self.index];
  if (question && !question.answered)
    question.skipped = true;

  self.index = elem.$index;
};

self.goToResult = function() {
  var question = self.questions[self.index];
  if (question && !question.answered)
    question.skipped = true;

  self.index = self.questions.length;
}

self.viewResult = function() {
  var hasError = false;

  angular.forEach(self.questions, function(question) {
    if (!question.answered) {
      hasError = true;
      question.skipped = true;
    }
  });

  if (hasError) {
    self.error = true;

    $timeout(function() {
      self.error = false;
    }, 2000);

    return false;
  }

  self.showQuiz = false;

  var result = getResult();
  self.job = result;
};

getResult = function() {
var results = [0, 0, 0];
var maior = -9999;
var iMaior = 0;

angular.forEach(self.userAnswers, function(answer) {
for (var i = 0; i < self.jobs.length; i++) {
  results[i] += answer.values[i];
}
});

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
var result = results[i];
if (result > maior) {
  maior = result;
  iMaior = i;
}
}

return iMaior;
};
}]);
```

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like the points correspond to the `values` attribute in each question, so you can change those to be "4,2,0" etc.

Comment: I have tried to A with "values: [4, 4, 4]". Option B to "values [2, 2, 2]". C  "values: [0, 0, 0]".

I can not do the sum and return the result according to the condition.

Comment: This is confusing.A plunker  demo would help. Also not clear where you are specifically having a problem in the code itself

Comment: In fact I do not need. My old code needed. In this modification I just need to sum the points and return the value in the true condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = getResult();

function getResult(){
    var totalScore = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.userAnswers.length; i++) {
      totalScore += self.userAnswers[i].values[0]; // assuming "values" is an array of equal values: [4,4,4],[2,2,2] or [0,0,0]
    }
    if(totalScore <= 10){
        return self.jobs[0]
    } else if (totalScore < 24) {
        return self.jobs[1]
    } else {
        return self.jobs[2]
    }
}
```

Comment: I put your code by replacing the lines that are after: `var result = getResult();
  self.job = result;
 }; ` and before `}]);` but the screen went white when he get the result.

Comment: @Wendell - A ideia era vc entender a logica e aplicar no seu codigo, nao copiar e colar. Eu reescrevi sua funcao `getResult `, pra verificar cada resposta, e somar o valor em `totalScore`, no fim verifica o valor total e retorna um dos tres jobs. Era isso que vc queria fazer?

Comment: é exatamente isso que quero fazer. Acredito que não precisava de nenhuma modificação. Porém não funcionou. Eu tenho experiência intermediária em PHP, mas javascript sou bem leigo.

Comment: sabe usar o console do browser? Vai te ajudar a achar o erro. - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/

Comment: Usei o depurador, ele indica que a função fez a verificação e retornou o resultado corretamente, porém o mesmo não é apresentado na tela. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: vc deve ter esquecido essa parte? `self.job = result`, que na verdade pode ser direto `self.job = getResult()`, dai nao precisa dessa var: `var result = getResult()`

Comment: eu realmente estou perdido. Fiz o que informou na sugestão, como pode ver [aqui](http://codepen.io/wendell_chrys/pen/kXEQdY) mas ainda assim aparece a tela branca.